# How to import SCSS mixins in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

Trying to figure out how to import some SCSS files in a Rails 4 app. The files are:

```
@import "shared/mixins",
        "shared/reset",
        "shared/about-light";
```

I'm not sure how to do this properly and I don't know how to set the path either.

I put these files in a folder called `"shared"` and I put this folder inside of `/lib/assets/css/` Is this the right way to do it?

Also tried to put the files in `/vendor/assets/stylesheets/`

How do I properly import these files?

Error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: mixins.
Load paths:
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We typically put mixins in a partial file called `_mixins.scss` directly in the `app/assets/stylesheets/` directory, possibly under a subdir like `shared` if you want more organization.  In your `application.css` you can then do (as you did)

```
@import 'shared/mixins';
@import 'shared/colors';
```

or whatever.  If you really want them to sit somewhere else, you should look into the `load_paths` configuration setting for SASS.  You can tell SASS where to look when it's importing files and probably `lib/assets` and `vendor/assets` are not included by default.

To add this configuration, in your `environment.rb` or other config file, you can do something like

```
config.sass.load_paths << File.expand_path('../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/')
```

which will make SASS look in `vendor/assets/stylesheets` in addition to all the other directories it searches in by default.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing partials and mixins.

From the Sass documentation:

**Mixin**

"A mixin lets you make groups of CSS declarations that you want to reuse throughout your site. You can even pass in values to make your mixin more flexible. You can think of a mixin like a function for css (awesome right!)." More about mixins [here](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6).

**Partial**

"You can create partial Sass files that contain little snippets of CSS that you can include in other Sass files. This is a great way to modularize your CSS and help keep things easier to maintain. A partial is simply a Sass file named with a leading underscore." More about partials [here](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4).

Therefore, what you are attempting to import are indeed **partials** and should be prefaced with an underscore.

Your directory structure should look like this:

```
assets
  stylesheets
    application.css.scss
    shared
      _mixins.scss
      _reset.scss
      _about-light.scss
```

And your application.css.scss file should look like this:

```
@import "mixins";
@import "rest";
@import "about-light";
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I was able to work this out as follows:

1. In `application.rb` add the following:

   `config.sass.load_paths << File.expand_path('../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/')`
2. In the CSS file import as:

   `@import "mixins",
           "reset",
           "about-light";`
3. Put the files in to:

   `/vendor/assets/stylesheets/`
4. Restart the server.